# React Axios `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` with more than 3 path components

Tags: reactjs, request, axios

I've come across an interesting issue where axios is blocking all requests to a path with more than 3 components.

For example: a `DELETE` request to `http://foo.com/one/two/three` works fine but the same request to `http://foo.com/one/two/three/four` is throwing an error:

```
net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Is this standard practice? Should I limit myself to 3 path components?